# mongoexport fails when I add --collection BrowserHistory

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoexport

I am trying to `mongoexport` a collection named,`BrowserHistory` from my DB. I have tried doing this through SSH into my CentOS server and a local MongoDB install on my computer. I have MongoDB *2.6* installed.

Note: I have obscured the server, etc. info

The commands I have tried and results are below:

```
 mongoexport --host host.xysz.com:27017 --username iamuser2 --password securepass --db test1ng1 --collection BrowserHistory --out ram.json
```

> Result: "Error parsing command line: too many positional options have
>   been specified on the command line try 'mongoexport --help' for more
>   information"

```
mongoexport --host host.xysz.com:27017 --username iamuser2 --password securepass --db test1ng1 --out ram.json
```

> Result: connected to: host.xysz.com:27017 no collection specified!
>   Export MongoDB data to CSV, TSV, or JSON files.

I need to output the collection into json file(s) so I can import it into Hive.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question for proper formatting Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the 'collection' parameter value has whitespace.
This can be overcome by enclosing it in single quote.

```
mongoexport --host host.xysz.com:27017 --username iamuser2 --password securepass --db test1ng1 --collection 'BrowserHistory' --out ram.json
```

Comment: I tried that before too and just tried it again but didn't work. Also, I tried with a collection named just one word - Friends

Comment: Do you have whitespace elsewhere in the command? Probably host param value?

Comment: I just tried enclosing everything in 's and still same error :(

Comment: Finally figured it out when taking the text from Textedit to Sublime Text 2. The "--" were getting converted and causing issues